# How to create test cycles using jira api

Tags: jira-rest-api, jira-zephyr

I need to know how to create new test cycles and and test cases to the cycle by using jira REST API.
Can someone drop a API to create jira test cyles.
I already referred zephyr documentation, no luck there.